# AdMob в приложениях

Tags: android, admob

Можно создать 1 баннер в AdMob и установить его на все Activity и Fragment которые нужно или для отображения на разных компонентах нужно создавать разные баннеры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У каждого баннера свой идентификатор. Для разных экранов нужно создавать разные.
Но можно на одной активности крутить баннер несмотря на то, что будут использоваться разные фрагменты.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.

Comment: А зачем разные? Насколько я понимаю так лишь информация будет о том, на каком экране рекламу смотрели/кликали. Что помешает использовать один ID везде? Это, конечно, не относится к случаю наличия более одного баннера на экране единомоментно.

Comment: Ничего не мешает, просто так принято. И так правильно. Однажды я эту информацию нашел в Гугловской справке.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать один банер в разных местах, но просто потом будет удобней отключать или включать отдельные банеры, например если будет сильно бесить пользователей